# How to use relative words instead of absolute words

Tags: word-choice, comparative-constructions

[image]

I am trying to describe the above drawing.  My examples are as follows:

> 1. A bank and a hospital are respectively located at distances of 5km
>      and 8km from ends, closer thereto, of a road.
> 2. A bank and a hospital are respectively located at distances of 5km
>          and 8km from their respective closer ends of a road.

Are my examples are understandable? I would like to describe using relative words such as closer rather than absolute words such as the left end and the right end.

---

CLARIFICATION
In a comment made below, the OP said

> "the resilient devices 118a and 118b are spaced at a distance D from the respective nearer end of the coil" I have found this sentence in a patent document. Is this sentence grammatically correct? My second example is similar to this

Comment: Are you trying to use the word **respectively** because you have to construct a sentence using the word, as a learning exercise? Or are you looking merely for a clear and succinct way of describing the situation depicted in the drawing?

Comment: I should add that "ends of a road" doesn't make much sense to me, since roads typically don't just dead-end.  They intersect other roads. Does this road dead-end in two places?  Is this question really about a road, or are you using a road merely as an analogue for something else?

Comment: There is no need to use "respectively ".  The "road" is a just example.  Something with two opposite ends can be replaced with the "road".

Comment: I've added the clarification because as TRomano stated, roads don't normally have dead-ends: eight or five kilometres from where? Where does this imaginary road begin?  On the other hand, the clarification makes sense, and it is easier to understand the reason for OP to invent this diagram and sentence.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, both of the proposed examples are overly wordy and complex; I would struggle to understand the meaning of either one.

As a general rule, *simpler is better*.

If I were to describe the picture, I would say this:

> A bank and a hospital are on opposite sides of a road. The bank is 5km from one end of the road. The hospital is 8km from the other end of the road.

The original question says:

> I would like to describe using relative words such as closer rather than absolute words such as the left end and the right end.

First: you don't need "closer" if you use the actual distances. You can rely on the reader to know that 5km < 8km.

The problem is that the diagram has 2 "ends of the road". One way or another, you have to communicate *which end of the road is which*. Any directions ("left/right", "north/south", "top/bottom") are *perfect* for this - these terms are short, clear, and specific. But if there's absolutely *no other way* to tell the ends of the road apart, then you could say:

> The bank is closer to one end of the road than the hospital is to the other end of the road.

This sentence should be generally understandable. However, compare it to this:

> The bank is closer to the left end of the road than the hospital is to the right end of the road.

I think the version with "left" and "right" is clearer, easier to read, and provides a more accurate "word picture" of the diagram.

But it's not that I'm hung up on "left" and "right" - the general point is that *some sort of context* is needed when making comparisons, and the more explicit that context is, the clearer the comparison will be.

You can use other context in other situations. For example, to describe the [QWERTY keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY), all of these sentences are valid:

> - The "D" key is 2 keys to the right of the "A" key, and the "H" key is 3 keys to the left of the "L" key.
> - The "D" key is closer to the "A" key than the "H" key is to the "L" key.
> - "D" and "A" are closer than "H" and "L".
> - The distance between "D" and "A" is less than the distance between "H" and "L".

These sentences are clear because the "A key" is distinct from the "L key"; these keys are clearly two different things.

Even if you can't use "left" and "right", having *some* way to distinguish between the ends of the road will make the sentence clearer.

Comment: "First: you don't need "closer" if you use the actual distances." Not so. **from their respective closer ends** specifically excludes a situation where, for example, the bank is 5km from one end and 4km from the other end, while the hospital is 8km from one end and 1km from the other end.

Comment: >>JavaLatte  I'm not sure I understand what you mean completely.  Do you mean that the expression "from their respective closer ends" can be used if actual distances are not referred to?  In fact I don't need to refer to actual distances.

Answer (score -1):

I would word it somewhat like this:

> A bank and a hospital are located 5km and 8km respectively from their
>   closest ends.

Comment: Why did you use closest rather than closer? There are only two ends, so shouldn't it be the same as the expression "the lesser of two evils", rather than "the least of two evils".

Comment: You're right. Either works when there are only 2 objects involved in context. But when there are more than 2 objects involved "closest" makes more sense. In my answer related to the OP's example it does not make a difference if we used closer or closes, but if the example involved a triangle instead of a straight road closest would be the correct (and more generic) solution